# Custom code after 3rd, 5th and 7th post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Hi there, I have a little bit of a problem. The front page of our new site has a series of thumbnail boxes with rollovers to open certain showcased products. The loop I have written shows all posts currently but will eventually be tied down only to the portfolio category.

My manager however wants a slider with recent blog posts after the third post and a couple of more sliders with references and suchlike after the 5th and 7th posts. I found a little bit of code that injects the same snippet every n posts but this is no good for me because I only want it to happen 3 times and all with different content, including one with a loop inside a loop (where presumably time will move mega slowly haha). Is this possible? If so, can anybody point me towards a code snippet?

Current Loop

```
        <!-- Start of loop -->
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <!-- Start of Post -->
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Check to see if there is featured image -->
        <?php if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
        <?php $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 960,960 )); ?>
        <!-- End Checking -->


        <div class="portfolioblock" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $img_src[0]; ?>');">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="rollover">
              <div class="center">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/zoom.png" alt="More" />
              </div>                    
              <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>               
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
        </a>
        </div>


          <!-- Start Content Block -->          
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="block">
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>               
          <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>            
        <?php } ?>
        <!-- End Content Block -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- End of Post -->

        <?php else : ?>
        //Something that happens when a post isn’t found.

    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- End of Loop -->
```

And I found this code for injecting a code snippet every n posts.

```
<?php $postnum++; if($postnum%5 == 0) { ?>
YOUR AD CODE HERE
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on cweiske's answer:

Inserted just before endwhile

```
    <?php $postnum++;
    if ($postnum == 4) { ?>

            <div class="block"><h2>Blog</h2></div>

    <?php } 
        if ($postnum == 6) { ?>

            <div class="block"><h2>References</h2></div>

    <?php }
        if ($postnum == 9) { ?>

            <div class="block"><h2>Meet the team</h2></div>

    <?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could count the number of posts that passed and then decide on that:

```
$postnum++;
if ($postnum == 3 || $postnum == 5 || $postnum == 7) {
    echo 'foo';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not brilliant with php in general. How would I add another loop into this?

Comment: ah no worries, figured it out:

Comment: '   <?php $postnum++;
                if ($postnum == 3) { ?>
            
            <div class="block"><h2>Blog</h2></div>
            
            <?php } ?>  
'

Comment: Actually, I need something a little more, this echos the same content over all three divs and I need to put different content in each.

Comment: again, figured it out, see below

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is this.

Before the loop begins, initialise a counter variable to 0.

Each time the loop successfully finds a post, increment the variable.

Now, each loop, you will know how many posts have been displayed.

So at the appropriate place, you check the counter to see if it matches either 3 5 or 7. If it does match, you display the correct block.